# Replacing characters in a text file from Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

I'm trying to write a batch file that will look at every character in a small text file (a CUE sheet, actually) and do three things -- remove all question marks, replace any slash marks with a hyphen and replace colons with two hyphens -- as per the second line in the example below.

```
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Colon:  Slash / Question Mark?"
(would be changed to)
    TITLE "Colon -- Slash - Question Mark"
```

I know how to use findstr to copy the lines containing those characters to a new text file (but only those lines), and not how to do the search-and-replace.  And findstr also has the unwanted consequence of removing leading spaces, which I wish to retain.  Not sure what's the right approach here.  (I should add that for various reasons I prefer not to use a third-party utility.)

Comment: It should be possible in principle, but perhaps 3rd party utilities like GNU SED would be more suited to the task.

Comment: @Magoo  check the answer below it works without 3rd Party (considering PowerShell shipped with Windows)

Comment: In your example you are not replacing a colon with two hypens, but with _a space_ and two hypens. `findstr` did _not_ remove leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks, AAcini.  You're right about the space and two hyphens, but FINDSTR also removes the leading spaces at the start of the line (in front of "Track" and "Title"), which is more what I was concerned about.  But Magoo's solution should take care of those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42482508.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:?=!"
 SET "line=!line:/=-!"
 SET "line=!line::=--!"
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42482508.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Invoke delayed expansion to allow strings to be manipulated in a code block.

Read each line of the file to `%%a` thence `line`; replace each `?` with *nothing*, `/` with one `-` and `:` with two, and `echo` the result.

Parenthesising the `for` allows redirection to the specified file.

The pattern is set "var1=!var2:*stringtoreplace*=*replacementstring*!" as documented, `!` in place of `%` to use delayedexpansion.

Note that your text specifies the replacemnt string for `:` as `--` whereas your example shows it being replaced by "<kbd>Space</kbd>--"

Comment: Thanks, Magoo.  I was not aware of this powerful feature of the SET command, and had been trying to use FOR loops to iterate through each character on every line, without success.

Comment: Speaking of which, is there a way to make your FOR block skip any line beginning with the word "INDEX?"

Comment: Certainly. Replace `"%filename1%"` with `'findstr /v /L /i /b /c:"INDEX?" "%filename1%"'` and remove the `usebackq`. `usebackq` instructs that a double-quoted string be interpreted as a filename, not a string (in case of spaces in the filename). The `findstr` command **must** be single-quoted and means `/v` lines that do not match `/L` literally `/i` case-insensitive (if required) `/b` beginning `/c:"characterstringtomatch"`. See `findstr /?` from the prompt for more info.

Comment: Thanks again, Magoo.

Man, how do you guys keep all the commands and options and switches, rules and limitations and feature sets, and quirks and bugs and workarounds straight?  I consider myself reasonably bright but find myself frequently tripping over all the little complexities.

Very grateful for your guidance.

Comment: Seems I'm still missing something.  If the first three lines of my input are `TRACK 01 AUDIO`
    `TITLE "This Title Has a Question Mark?"` and 
    `INDEX 01 04:36:52` the corresponding output now is `TRACK` 
`TITLE` and 
`INDEX`  when all I'm trying to do is get it to ignore the colons in the line beginning with "INDEX."

Comment: Figured it out.  FINDSTR was the solution, but I needed to do something more like this `for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%FILE%") do (` 
    `set "LINE=%%a"`
    `echo !LINE! | findstr /i /c:"INDEX" > nul & if errorlevel 1 (` inside an IF block before echoing the %LINE%.

Answer (score 7):

**You can use Powershell to solve this very easily.**

Open PowerShell and type this

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\Admin\StackOverflow\some.txt).Replace(":"," - -") | Set-Content C:\Users\Admin\StackOverflow\SomeModified.txt
```

Basically,

**Get-Content** will open the file.

**.Replace** to replace the text(old text, new text)

**| Set-Content** < path > to output on diffrent file.

**Screenshots**
[image: Source File]
[image: Powershell Command]
[image: Destination File Post Change]

Comment: Thanks, Baljeetsingh, but my batch file has to be backwards-compatible with Windows PCs that don't have .Net Framework -- thus, no Powershell.  I really need to figure out how to write this in Windows batch.

Comment: Some environments don't allow PowerShell scripts to run

Comment: @ChadLehman yes I understand that not every tech is available on every platform. We can take advantage where every applicable. For that matter bat file works only on windows.