# trying to change delimiters in large csv files resulting in memory errors (python 3)

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of comma-delimited files that I am trying to change to pipe-delimited files.

I am following the example provided here: [Python CSV change separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256104/python-csv-change-separator/49414740)

Here is my code:

```
print("setting new delimiter...")
reader = list(csv.reader(open(localfile, "rU"), delimiter=','))
writer = csv.writer(open(localfile, 'w'), delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerows(row for row in reader)
```

I can't tell if memory usage is cumulative, or because of a specific filesize, but either way, on my third file, I get a `memory error`.

since the third file is nearly the same size as the first two, it appears cumulative.

Is there a better way in doing this?  Thanks

Comment: Dont use `list` on the `csv.reader`... it's iterable... then just use `writer.writerows(reader)`... (you don't need a gen-exp there)

Comment: You never actually close the file btw

Comment: should I?  just `reader.close()`