# Replace ':' in CSV with ','

Tags: python, csv, replace

Hey guys I wanted to code a little program, and I have this code

```
inputfile = csv.reader(open('data.csv','r'))
for row in inputfile:
```

but now I have the problem, that I have commas and `:` in my CSV and I want to replace the `':'` with a comma, because I want to read it in with the `row[3]` function for example. Or is it possible without replacement?
thank you guys!

```
inputfile = csv.reader(open('data.csv','r'))
for row in inputfile:
    xyc = row[0]
    afs = row[1]
    yxcva = row[2]
    asdfe = row[3]
```

I tried that already:

```
data = ""

with `open("input.csv")` as file:
     data = file.read().replace(":", ",")

with `open("data.csv")` as file:
     file.write(data)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and the expected result. It's not clear if you want to edit the original file, or simply need a way to parse each line into four fields.

Comment: Do you actually want to re-write the file, or just read it properly? Either way, use the `delimiter` paramter of `reader`.

Comment: Or do you mean the CSV file uses _both_ `,` and `:` as delimiter? On the same line, or on different lines? Does the file hold string data that might itself contain a `,` or `:`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python CSV change separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256104/python-csv-change-separator)

Comment: if it could use both (, and :) as delimiter that would be fine too 
sample input in data.csv abs,jkel,dheu:kljsk:3234:2324
sample output in another file abs,jkel,dheu,kljsk,3234,2324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the a for loop like that and you want to split the line, you can do something like

```
elements = row.split(',')
xyc = elements[0]
abc = elements[1]
...
```

The parameter in the [split command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) tells the method which char to use to do the split
!

Comment: can i also let it split with , and : ?

Comment: i think in that case you could use `row.replace(':',',').split(',')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace

Comment: you need to use replace before split, because split creates a list, but replace returns a String. This works for me ```a = "This,is:a:String,or,something"

data = a.replace(':', ',').split(',')
print(data) ```

Comment: This is because you use the csv.reader! Try the following:  ´´´ input = open('data.csv','r')
for row in input:
  data = row.replace(':', ',').split(',')
  print(data) ´´´